# What is the connector used on the Samsung AMS495QA01 Screen?

Tags: connector

Its on some screen(s?) made by samsung however i do not know where i can find the connector itself. which is what im after.

[image: Connector]

Comment: Samtech something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Board side:
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF40C-40DS-0-4V-51/H11625CT-ND/1767349

Flex side:
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/hirose-electric-co-ltd/DF40C-40DP-0-4V-51/H11624CT-ND/1969504

This is digikey's connector category for this type of connector. If the above aren't the exact match, you may be able to find it on here instead: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-board-to-board-connectors-arrays-edge-type-mezzanine/308